# How is the URL's request dynamic in a Ruby in Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, url, dynamic

I'm learning Rails and using 'Agile Development with Rails, Fourth Edition - Prag. Prog.'.

I understand the processing of a user's request, in RoR, to be like this:

1. The user's request is defined in the url, in order to communicate with the app's code
2. The url request is then processed by RoR - the specific Controller right for the particular request is defined, and so is the user's action
3. Taking as reference the defined user's action, a View template is selected to output a response to the request/action (a template that can have attributes of the selected Controller, like instance variables)

So, that's what i've understood so far - is this how the dynamic URL is created in a RoR app?

Thanks in advance! I find this complex but I'm trying to learn!

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Yes, the user creates the request, and it's processed by Rails, and a view template is rendered back to the user. Except for the Rails part, that describes every web app in every framework ever.

Comment: What exactly is your understanding of the term `the dynamic`?

Comment: I mean the way that the request is processed, taking as reference the dynamic between the MVC, you know? The way that the MVC communicates, when a user make a request.

Comment: But the source explicitly defines how the parts communicate, or uses convention to define how they communicate. The question still isn't clear to me; sorry.

Comment: Well Dave, i'm a beginner... so maybe i simply did not express my  question right. What i want with this question is to check out if i'm missing something, when it comes to how the MVC works when a user makes a request. Taking as references the stuff that i wrote, i described the process in the right way?

Comment: Dave is right as this is not really a question but more of a discussion you want to start. StackOverflow is for specific needs and problems. Forums would be of a better help next time ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is dynamic because it identifies the resource(s) in question with the contents of the query string identifying particular records.

So for examples a url of

```
www.blob.com/books/23
```

Is for Info about the book with an id of 23

whereas

```
www.blob.com/books/436
```

is for a different book, hence dynamic as `www.blob.com/books/` was the same

In terms of MVC:

- The clients browser initiates a request and says which resource and operation they want, e.g. books/23
- Then the request is made to the web server and the rails app and the resources name(s) and identifier(s) are passed along.  Within the rails app the first stop is actually routing to determine which controller to call and then call that controller.
- The controller will be fairly generic at this point as all resources will be treated similarly, the key thing is next when the controller then requests the information from...
- The model layer and the underlying database, which is when then the dynamic record ID's come into play.
- The controller which made this call to the model will then prepare the view page and have it sent out from the web server back to the browser that made the request.

Comment: Sorry, i think that you did not understand my question... or it was me the one who explained stuff wrongly?

Comment: I'm asking how the dynamic between the MVC (Model, View, Controller) works in the processing of a user's request

Comment: So the comunication with the data base occours when the Model comes into play, requested by the controller, right?